# Check if many2many contain a value

Tags: python, odoo-8, odoo

I want to check if a value is contained in a many2many field

```
my_own_m2m = fields.Many2many("a.table", string="My Own Many2many")
```

I tried with

```
for value in my_own_m2m :
    if (value.id == self.env.ref('some_external_id').id):
        hooray_i_found_it = True
```

Can we do it with something like

```
if self.env.ref('some_external_id').id in my_own_m2m:
```

I've tried it but cannot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
if self.env.ref('some_external_id').id in my_own_m2m.mapped('id'):
    ...
```

Comment: can we do the same inside xml? for example in attrs="{'invisible':[(%('some_external_id')d,'not in','my_own_m2m.mapped('id')')]}"

Comment: No, in a domain (like the one used in `attrs`) it's mandatory to write a field name in the left part each tuple.

Comment: Can you give an example? I don't know how to write a field name in the left part each tuple

Comment: I mean that you can't put whatever in the left part of the tuples, like in your example, you're putting an integer (`%('some_external_id')d`). Instead you must write a field of the current model which is in the current XML view, e.g: `id` is a field each model has, so `attrs="{'invisible':[('id', 'not in', my_own_m2m.mapped('id'))]}"`. In this example, you must have written `<field name="id"/>` above, but in the same view.

Comment: First off `in my_own_m2m.ids` is enough, no need for `mapped`. And then the other thing. It could work with a domain like `[('my_own_m2m.ids', '=', ref('some_external_id'))]` but depends if `ref()` is usable in `attrs` domains, which i dont know at exact his moment ;-)

Comment: Another info: this domain style "x2many_field_ids = id_of_something" is like a reverse "in". You can read it as "id_of_something in x2many_field_ids".